# Find minimum in a constrained two-variable inequation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: find minimum 
$$9a^2+9b^2+c^2$$
where $a^2+b^2\leq 9, c=\sqrt{9-a^2}\sqrt{9-b^2}-2ab$

Comment: For sure, there is the [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) method. But maybe there is smart shortcut.

Comment: Assuming the inequality to be an equality find limits of solution in a doubly constrained problem with two Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$ F(a,b)=9(a^2+b^2)+(\sqrt{(9-a^2)(9-b^2)}-2ab)^2. $$
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}&=&\frac{2 b (18 (-9 + b^2) - 4 a^2 (-9 + b^2) + 
   5 a b \sqrt{(-9 + a^2) (-9 + b^2)})}{\sqrt{(-9 + a^2) (-9 + b^2)}},\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}&=&\frac{2 a (a^2 (18 - 4 b^2) + 5 a b \sqrt{(-9 + a^2) (-9 + b^2)} + 18 (-9 + 2 b^2))}{\sqrt{(-9 + a^2) (-9 + b^2)}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Letting $\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}=0$ gives $a=b=0,a=b=\pm\sqrt{2}$ which satisfies $a^2+b^2\le 9$. But $F(0,0)=81,F(\pm\sqrt{2},\pm\sqrt{2})=45$. So when $a=b=\pm\sqrt{2}$, $F$ reaches the minimum which is 45.

Another way is just to use the following inequality
$$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n\ge n\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n} $$
and the equal holds if and only if $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n$. In fact
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(a,b)-45&=&9 (a^2 + b^2) + (\sqrt{(9 - a^2) (9 - b^2)} - 2 a b)^2\\
&=&36 + 5 a^2 b^2 - 4 a b \sqrt{(9 - a^2) (9 - b^2)}\\
&=&\frac{(36 + 5 a^2 b^2)^2 - (4 a b \sqrt{(9 - a^2) (9 - b^2)})^2}{36 + 5 a^2 b^2 - 4 a b \sqrt{(9 - a^2) (9 - b^2)}}\\
&=&\frac{144+a^4b^4+16a^2b^2(a^2+b^2)-104a^2b^2}{36 + 5 a^2 b^2 - 4 a b \sqrt{(9 - a^2) (9 - b^2)}}\\
&=&\frac{a^2b^2}{36 + 5 a^2 b^2 - 4 a b \sqrt{(9 - a^2) (9 - b^2)}}\left(a^2b^2+16(a^2+b^2)+\frac{144}{a^2b^2}-104\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
But
\begin{eqnarray*}
a^2b^2+16(a^2+b^2)+\frac{144}{a^2b^2}&=&a^2b^2+\overbrace{2a^2+\cdots+2a^2}^8+\overbrace{2b^2+\cdots+2b^2}^8+\overbrace{\frac{16}{a^2b^2}+\cdots+\frac{16}{a^2b^2}}^9\\
&\ge&26\sqrt[26]{a^2b^2(2a^2)^8(2b^2)^8\left(\frac{16}{a^2b^2})\right)^9}\\
&=&104.
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus $F(a,b)-45\ge 0$ or $F(a,b)\ge 45$. The equal sign holds if and only if 
$$ a^2b^2=2a^2=2b^2=\frac{16}{a^2b^2} $$
or equivalently $a=b=\pm\sqrt{2}$. Thus $F(a,b)$ reaches the minimum 45 when $a=b=\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this comes to your rescue.

Consider $b \ge a \ge 0$

When you expansion of $(\sqrt{9-a^2}\sqrt{9-b^2}-2ab)^2=(9-a^2)(9-b^2)+4a^2b^2-4ab \sqrt{(9-a^2)(9-b^2)}$

This attains minimum when $4ab \sqrt{(9-a^2)(9-b^2)}$ is maximum.

Applying **AM-GM** :

$\dfrac{9-a^2+9-b^2}{2} \ge \sqrt{(9-a^2)(9-b^2)} \implies 9- \dfrac{9}{2} \ge \sqrt{(9-a^2)(9-b^2)}$

$\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2} \ge ab \implies 18 \ge 4ab$

Comment: We can't really rely that minimum of $c^2$ gives minimum for $9a^2+9b^2+c^2$ also, can we?  Otherwise flipping the argument, $9a^2 + 9b^2$ is minimum when $a=b=0$.

Comment: @Macavity: Totally agree with you.

Comment: And @xpaul: I answered it, and he knows that it is not the right method. :)

Answer (score 1):

$ 9a^2+9b^2+c^2=9a^2+9b^2+(9-a^2)(9-b^2)-4ab\sqrt{9-a^2}\sqrt{9-b^2}+4a^2b^2$

=$81+5a^2 b^2-4ab \sqrt{9^2-9(a^2+b^2)+a^2b^2} $

$\ge 81+5a^2 b^2-4|ab|\sqrt{9^2-9(a^2+b^2)+a^2 b^2} $     $  (-ab \ge -|ab|)$

$\ge 81+5a^2 b^2-4|ab|\sqrt{9^2-9(2|ab|)+a^2 b^2}$    $(a^2+b^2 \ge 2|ab|)$

=$81+5a^2 b^2-4|ab|(9-|ab|)$=$9a^2b^2-36|ab|+81$

$=9(|ab|-2)^2+45 \geq 45$ , $ (9(|ab|-2)^2 \ge 0)$

first "=", $ab \ge 0$, 2nd  "=", $|a|=|b|$, last "=", $|ab|=2$, so we got the min is 45 when $a=b=\pm \sqrt{2}$

with same method, we can get max also.

Edit: I add max in same way:

$81+5a^2 b^2-4ab \sqrt{9^2-9(a^2+b^2)+a^2b^2}  $

$\leq  81+5a^2 b^2+4|ab| \sqrt{9^2-9(a^2+b^2)+a^2b^2}$   $  (-ab \leq |ab|)$
$ \leq 81+5(\dfrac{a^2+ b^2}{2})^2+4*\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2} \sqrt{9^2-9(a^2+b^2)+( \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2} )^2} $  $ ( |ab| \leq \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}, a^2 b^2 \leq (\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2})^2)$

$=81+5x^2+4x(9-x)=81+x^2+36x    $ ......... $  here:  x=\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2} \leq \dfrac{9}{2}  $

$\leq 81+(\dfrac{9}{2})^2+36*\dfrac{9}{2}=\dfrac{567}{4}$

when $a=-b=\pm \dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: Neat (+1), though you need to correct the first expansion (it should be $-4ab\dots$.  Not sure if this method can give max though.

Comment: @Macavity: thanks, I correct error. for max, I add the details in answer.

Comment: Your method is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach - the symmetry here suggests Purkiss Principle (conditions to be verified), so the extremum is attained when $a = b$.

So $c = (9-a^2) - 2a^2 = 9-3a^2$
and $9(a^2+b^2) + c^2 = 18a^2 + (9-3a^2)^2 = 9a^4 - 36a^2 + 81 = 9 (a^2 - 2)^2 + 45$

which is minimised when $a^2 = 2$ or $a = \pm \sqrt2$.